# Setting up Microsoft Office on High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, ms-office

The computers at my work are all old iMac11,2s which consequently can't be updated to a supported OS. What I did, therefore, was download an older version of Office, I can't remember which now but basically it was the last version supported on High Sierra.

I then ran straight into another wall because Office asked me to sign in, and the Microsoft Account is with GoDaddy, and when I enter the email address I just get a grey screen from them because they no longer support this version of Office.

I can get into GoDaddy from Chrome but not from Office's own app. But I figured, 'well, at home I never have to sign in again when I change to another version of Office because the sign-in settings are stored separately, maybe I can sign in elsewhere to set up the account then just skip the sign in screen'.

And that's where I'm up to. I'm honestly not really an Apple person. I'm definitely not a 13 year old iMac person, so I'm pretty much stumped. I have a working version of Office but I can't get into the thing. Is there any way of getting this working or do I just have to accept using the online versions of Office instead of the apps?

Comment: What do you mean with "Microsoft Account is with GoDaddy", is this a special license you got via GoDaddy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Microsoft Account being with GoDaddy = it's a corporate email address with a domain obtained via GoDaddy. When opening any Office program, I'm prompted to enter the account details in order to activate Office. Upon entering the email address, I'm sent to a GoDaddy portal, which no longer works because I'm having to use an old version of Office which it appears is no longer supported. That's a conjecture, the fact is that I just get to the stage of being sent to GoDaddy then get faced with a grey screen that has the GoDaddy logo at the top.

Comment: Have you asked GoDaddy for help?

Answer (score 1):

Version 16.43 and earlier versions of Office 2019 will work on High Sierra; however, it may be difficult to obtain them now that newer versions have been released.

Office 2016 will work, but Microsoft no longer sells it, nor supports it. If you can get an installer, you still need an authorisation/licence code to link it to your Microsoft account and activate it on your computer.

Office 2011 may not work properly on High Sierra. [Does Microsoft Office 2011 work in High Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315802/does-microsoft-office-2011-work-in-high-sierra)

If these 2010 iMacs had been installed with Office in the years between 2016 and October 2020 (when support for Office 2016 ended), then you would not have this problem now. In short: it's a curious time in the lifespan of these Macs to decide that they suddenly need Office.

Realistically, if your company wants people to do their job, it needs to invest in some new computers and relevant software.

Comment: https://macadmins.software is an unofficial database of links to the *true* MS downloads for Office versions right back to 2015 [including 16.43]. They're not 'dodgy' or pirated, it's just a list of official links, otherwise hard to find.

Comment: Hello, OP here. Installing Office isn't the problem, it's activating it. Office is there, it would work, but we need to connect the valid Microsoft Account (through GoDaddy) with the purchased product to the application, and the specific portal for doing that is no longer supported. We also can't log in via (our old version of) Safari, but Chrome works (despite also being outdated). 

As to why we're using these computers, and Office wasn't installed previously, these are restored Macs purchased by the company, every other Mac in the office has Office installed, this was a new acquisition.

Comment: @RHuczok Your company just bought some 13-year-old Macs....?

Comment: Download official old versions of Office at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-for-mac